# Locating a fault in writing a variable

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm writing this piece of code for Arduino Uno, which takes in input on pin 2 the value of a PIR sensor. In order to debug, in this moment I'm taking the signal on pin 2 from the 5V power supply:

```
int inputPinSensor1 = 2; // input pin for sensor 1
int sensor_1_State = LOW; // we start assuming no motion detected for sensor 1
int val = 0; // variable for reading the pin status

void setup() {
  pinMode(inputPinSensor1, INPUT); // declare sensor 1 pin as input

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  detectChange(&inputPinSensor1, &sensor_1_State);
}

void detectChange(int* inputPin, int* pirState) {
  // read input value
  val = digitalRead(*inputPin);
  // check if the input is HIGH
  if (val == HIGH) {
    if (*pirState == LOW) {
      // we have just turned on
      Serial.println("Current detected");
      *pirState = HIGH;
    }
  } else {
    if (*pirState == HIGH){
      // we have just turned off
      Serial.println("Current ended");
      *pirState = LOW;
    }
  }
}
```

This code should detect the passage from a LOW value to an HIGH value on pin 2, and vice versa. In this way I'm expecting to have an HIGH value on pin 2 when I connect the jumper and a LOW value when I disconnect the jumper. But what I get is two possible behaviors: sometimes I get "Current detected" at the begin of the execution, after which there are no further messages, and sometimes I get a rapid alternation of "Current detected" and "Current ended".

Comment: You disconnect a wire? Disconnected does not equal LOW. Disconnected equals "Unknown". LOW is connected to GND.  What you have there is a "floating input".

Comment: As a side note, the input pins detect voltage, not current.

Comment: @Majenko [at]EdgarBonet Thank you for your answers. Yes, I was able to get the LOW value read when I connected the jumper to ground. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Majenko says in their comments, a pin that's not connected to anything "floats" and gives unpredictable results.

You either need to connect such a pin to ground through a "pull-down" resistor or to +5V through a "pull-up" resistor. (10KΩ is a good value to start with.)

If you connect the pin to +5V through a pull-up resistor then you would ground it to change it's state. In that case the pin reads HIGH normally, and drops to LOW when triggered. Note that the Arduino has a special mode, INPUT_PULLUP, that connects the pin to an internal pull-up resistor. In that case you don't need an external pull-up resistor.

In your case, connect the pin to ground with a 10KΩ restistor. Then when you want the pin to go high attach the pin to +5V. That will swamp the connection to ground and pull the pin up to just below 5V.